# T-test: connection between power and critical region

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, statistical-power

Let's say that I have a feature $x \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ and I want to test $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against, for instance, an alternative that $\mu < \mu_0$. Then I have two possibilities:

1. **For an unknown $\sigma$** I can use an estimator $S =\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2$. Then my statistics is $T=\frac{\bar X-\mu_0}{S}\sqrt n$ and if $H_0$ is true, then $T$ follows a $N(0,1)$ distribution with critical region $CR = (-\infty, -z_{1-\alpha}]$
2. **For a known $\sigma$** my test statistics is $T=\frac{\bar X-\mu_0}{\sigma}\sqrt n$ and if $H_0$ is true, then $T$ follows a $t(n-1)$ distribution with critical region $CR=(-\infty, -t_{1-\alpha}^{[n-1]}]$

The question is: which test is more powerful for an identical alternative hypothesis, supposing that $S = \sigma$? I know that $Power=\mathbb P(T \in CR \ | \ H_1)$ so it basically comes down to comparing critical regions, as test statistics are equal, am I right? But in that case it is all sample-size based, just to know for what $n$ we have $t_{1-\alpha}^{[n-1]}< z_{1-\alpha}$ or contrary.

Comment: In the preliminary design of a study one may plan to test at significance level $\alpha = 0.05.$ Under $H_0$ one finds a critical value $c$ giving that $\alpha.$ $\alpha=P(Rej|\sigma_0).$ // Then the same critical value is used to find the power against a specific alternative, say $\sigma_a.$, Power is $P(Rej|\sigma_a).$ Thus the critical value $c$ also determines power values.// If $\alpha$ is made smaller, then $c$ is adjusted accordingly to make Rejection Region smaller. Consequence is that power is also made smaller.

Comment: @BruceET you are right, but let's suppose, that $\alpha$ is fixed.